# How can I open a tab in terminal and run a command

Tags: shell, terminal

I want to open a tab in mac's terminal through a script and then run a process while that script is running in the original Terminal tab.  Can I do that?

Comment: You mean that You want to do all of these in one terminal? Google "GNU Screen"

Comment: Which terminal emulator, or an actual tty?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, i want to do this from a script.  I'll make a quick edit.

Comment: You may need/want to look into applescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you're running a GUI or not.
 Either way, however, you can tell a process to run in the background by add a '&' to the end of the command. for instance:
`user$ ./myexecutable &`
 This will run the exectuable 'myexecutable' but allow you to still type in additional commands to the terminal.

Comment: I just saw your comment that you are on a Mac command line, I had assumed Linux.

Comment: Sorry, I made some edits to make the question less broad.

Answer (score 1):

I think Control+Shift+T should do it.

Answer (score 1):

‘`tfork`’ script always opens a new terminal